# Fast algorithm to find exactly k columns in binary matrix such that the sum of those columns is the 1-vector

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, matrix, linear-algebra

Suppose I have an (M x N) binary matrix where both M and N can be large. I want to find exactly k columns (k is relatively small, say less than 10) such that the sum of those k columns is the 1-vector (all elements are 1). One solution is adequate. Is there a fast algorithm for this?

For example, an algorithm working on the matrix

```
1 0 0
1 0 0
1 1 0
0 1 1
```

with k=2 should return columns 0 and 2, but should report no solutions if k=1 or k=3.

I've tried two approaches:

1. The slow combinatorial approach where I try all (N choose k) combinations and find the combination that sums to the 1-vector. This runs in O(N^k) time which is obviously horrendous.
2. A recursive approach, which is faster but still runs in O(N^k) worst-case time. The Python code is as below:

```
import numpy as np

def recursiveFn(mat, col_used_bool, col_sum_to_date, cols_to_go):
    N = len(mat)
    if cols_to_go == 1:
        col_unused = 1 - col_sum_to_date
        if list(col_unused) in [list(i) for i in mat]:
            return (True, [col_unused])
        else:
            return (False, None)
    for col_id in range(N):
        if col_used_bool[col_id]:
            continue
        if 2 not in mat[col_id]+col_sum_to_date:
            col_used_bool[col_id] = True
            x = recursiveFn(mat, col_used_bool, mat[col_id]+col_sum_to_date, cols_to_go-1)
            col_used_bool[col_id] = False
            if x[0]:
                return (True, x[1] + [mat[col_id]])
    return (False, None)

exMat = [[1,1,1,0],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1]] #input by colums
exMat = [np.asarray(i) for i in exMat]
k = 2
output = recursiveFn(mat = exMat, col_used_bool = [False for i in exMat], 
    col_sum_to_date = np.asarray([0 for i in exMat[0]]), cols_to_go = k)
print(output[1])
### prints this : [array([0, 0, 0, 1]), array([1, 1, 1, 0])]
```

I'm unsatisfied with either of these approaches, and I feel that a smarter and faster algorithm exists. Thanks very much for your help. This is my first post on StackOverflow, so please be gentle with me if I made a faux-pas somewhere!

(If interested, I've also [asked the same question on Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3727899/801803), but there I'm less concerned about algorithmic efficiency and more concerned about mathematical techniques.)

Comment: You have a binary matrix but if I understand well, the sum is a classical integer addition, not a binary addition (Z/2Z).Besides, what is the maximum value of N?

Comment: You're right in that this is classical integer addition and not GF(2). N can be say 10^6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first attempt would be [integer-programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) using one of the available high-performance solvers (e.g. [Cbc](https://github.com/coin-or/Cbc)).

Assuming *some sparsity* in your incidence-matrix, those will be very efficient and are quite general (side-constraints / adaptations). They are also complete and might be able to prove infeasibility.

A simple formulation would look like:

```
Instance

c0 c1 c2
1  0  0  r0
1  0  0  r1
1  1  0  r2
0  1  1  r3

IP:

minimize(0)        # constant objective | pure feasibility problem

sum(c_i) = k       # target of columns chosen

r0 = 1 = c0        # r0 just showing the origin of the constraint; no real variable!
r1 = 1 = c0
r2 = 1 = c0 + c1
r3 = 1 = c1 + c2

c_i in {0, 1}      # all variables are binary
```

It might be possible to strenghten this formulation by additional inequalities like clique-inequalities (conflict-graph -> maximal-cliques), but not sure if that helps. Good solvers will do something similar *dynamically* be generating *cuts*.

A lot of theory is available. One keyword would be [exact cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) or all those packing/covering problems which are very similar.

Simple code-example:

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
                 [1, 0, 0],
                 [1, 1, 0],
                 [0, 1, 1]])

def solve(k, data):
  c = cp.Variable(data.shape[1], boolean=True)

  con = [data * c == 1,
         cp.sum(c) == k,
         c >= 0,
         c <= 1]

  obj = cp.Minimize(0)
  
  problem = cp.Problem(obj, con)
  problem.solve(verbose=True, solver=cp.GLPK_MI)

  if(problem.status == 'optimal'):
    return np.where(np.isclose(c.value, 1.0) == True)[0]
  else:
    assert problem.status == 'infeasible'
    return None

print(solve(2, data))
print(solve(1, data))
print(solve(3, data))

# [0 2]
# None
# None
```

Remarks:

- The code uses cvxpy which is very powerful, but lacks some advanced integer-programming support

  - The only easy to use non-commercial solver is `GLPK`, which is very good, but usually cannot compete with `Cbc`
  - The very algebraic usage of cvxpy together with some interface-decisions lead to the *unusual variable-bounds as constraints* formulation here

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I am unfamiliar with exact cover problems, so thanks for your suggestions. I'll try out what you suggest and will mark as answered if it helped!

Comment: What is the time complexity for this solution?

Comment: As the problem is probably np-hard, it's of course exponential in the number of columns. But when tackling np-hard problems, don't get thwarted by theoretical worst-case behaviours.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the first answer, it is an *Exact cover* problem, which is NP-hard. A classical way to address NP-hard problem is backtracking.

When considering backtracking, generally, the devil lies in the details. Different implementations can provide quite different results.

Historically, Knuth proposed [Algorithm X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_Algorithm_X) which is a recursive, nondeterministic, depth-first, backtracking algorithm.

This algorithm is worth being tested here.

However, due to the fact that only a small number `k` of columns are to be selected, I would try another approach, i.e. a classical backtracking algorithm with a boolean `b[j]` indicating if column `j` is selected, with two additional tricks.

1. When adding column `j` to the current sum of columns, we can stop the process as soon as a "2" is encountered, we don't need to wait for the final sum to be calculated
2. Instead of adding the column elements one by one, we can group `p` elements (corresponding to p rows) of each column into one integer, to accelerate the process of summing columns. We need to select the base for that. A small base allow to avoid too large numbers (this is important to limit the size of the ``isValid[]` array, see hereafter).

A base 2 is not possible: for example adding (1 0) and (1 0) will give (0 1), which is still a valid number.

Therefore, I propose to use a **base 3**, which allows to detect the presence of an erroneous "2" during the summation. For example,

```
V(0 1 1 0) = 0*3**0 + 1*3**1 +1*3**2 + 0*3**3
```

In practice, for analyzing groups of "p" elements, we need a boolean table of size "3**p", `isValid[]`, which will allow to detect immediately if a given obtained integer is valid. This table must be preprocessed during the initialization phase.

We know that we have obtained the 1-vector when all the integers are equal to a specific value `(3**p - 1)/2`, noting that the last group may have a different size `p' < p`.

Due to the large value of n, a last trick could be tested:

3. Look for valid solutions for a number of rows `n1 < n`, and then, for each candidate solution obtained, check if it is really a solution for all n rows.